# GTK window resize disable without going back to default

Tags: gtk

So I have this app that's a wee bit too small and so I'm trying to call `gtk_window_resize()` to, well, resize it. Problem is when I call `gtk_window_set_resizable()` and pass FALSE, being window not resizable, I revert back to my default size: too small.

Is there a way to have a permanent resized unresizable window?

Answer (score 6):

`gtk_window_set_resizable(window, FALSE)` will disable all resizing of a window, even resizing that you initiated programmatically. Instead, set the size request of the window or a widget within it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flipping the order of execution? Try first setting resizable to FALSE in `gtk_window_resizable()` and then resizing with `gtk_widget_set_size_request()`